# $ \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^{t}|g(s)|ds=0?$, when $\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)|=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

I was proving something with about differential equations and I stumbled on a problem which was cited in my book as trivial, but I don´t see it clearly:

So we have some function $g$ with:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)|=0$$

How to show that:

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^{t}|g(s)|ds=0?$$

*** EDIT: ***
The question is related to the answer to the following post: [Diff equations-Duhamels formula for $t\to\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240775/diff-equations-duhamels-formula-for-t-to-infty?rq=1)
What was meant here by "Then it's easy to show that the r.h.s. converges to zero."

Comment: That looks pretty false: $g(t)=1/t$

Comment: @OliverDiaz We assume that $|g(t)|=0$, when $t$ tends to infinity, but how to show that from that follows that the integral equals 0.

Comment: @Icv I have edited my post with more explanation

Comment: The statement of your problem is false unless $g\equiv0$ almost surely (wr.t Lebesgue measure)

Comment: @jcg we can assume that the function is continuous or? And if yes, how to show that for integral?

Comment: Okay, thank you! But could you look under the link and explain to me what was meant in the answer that it is easy to show that the r.h.s. tends to zero

Comment: The linked question has almost nothing to do with what you asked. By the way, in the linked question you need to know how $g(t)$ behaves at infinity in order to prove the claim.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ (measurable) satisfies $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int^t_0|g(s)|\,ds=0$ then $\int^A_0|g(s)|\,ds\leq\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int^t_0|g(s)|\,ds=0$ which means that $g=0$ a.s on any interval $[0,A]$ and so over on the whole real line.  Bottom line, the only solution to your problem is $g\equiv0$ (a.s).

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you check the answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240775/diff-equations-duhamels-formula-for-t-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1 and then explain what was meant by "Then it's easy to show that the r.h.s. converges to zero." And how did they came to that tendency without assuming that, the integral is zero as well.

Comment: In that problem, they have an exponential with linear (but negative) exponent times an integral which as you can check grows linearly ($\int^t_0|g|\leq \int^{t_0}_0|g| + \varepsilon (t-t_0)$)

Comment: and we are allowed, as in that post to apply MVT to only one function under integral? We don´t have to apply it on both?

Comment: the met was used there to bring an exponential out of the integrand, the rest is just a matter of competing factors: one decaying exponentially, the other growing at most linearly.

Answer (score 0):

Having $ g\left(t\right)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $, it is possible for $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} $ to converge to some value other than $ 0 $, which is the case for $ g:t\mapsto\mathrm{e}^{-t^{2}} $. It is also possible for $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} $ to diverge, taking, for example, $ g:t\mapsto\frac{\sin{t}}{t} $.

Comment: "$ \lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|}=0 $ is a necessary condition for $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} $ to converge." - That's not true. Pick your favorite absolutely convergent series (such as $\sum a_n = \sum 1/n^2$), and let $g$ be the function formed by summing triangles (or other shapes) centered at $t=n$ with height $1$ and area $a_n$.

Comment: I did not quite understand how you've defined your $ g $ function, could you explain more ?

Comment: For definiteness, let $$h(t) = \begin{cases}1-2|t| & \text{ if }|t| \leq 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$ (so $h$ is a triangle with base equal to the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$ and height equal to $1$). Then $$g(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h(n^2(t-n))$$ is the sum of shifted and scaled copies of $h$ where the $n$th triangle is centered at $t=n$, has height $1$, and base equal to the interval $[n-\frac{1}{2n^2}, n+\frac{1}{2n^2}]$, hence area equal to $\frac{1}{2n^2}$.

Comment: Since $g(n) = 1$ for all positive integers $n$, clearly $|g(t)|$ does not converge to zero as $t \to \infty$. But $\int |g(t)| = \sum\frac{1}{2n^2}$, which is finite.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not mention it. I meant that if $ g $ is continuous, then $ \lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|}=0 $ is a necessary condition for $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} $ to converge. If $ g $ is piecewise continuous but not continuous, then it is obviously possible for $ \lim\limits_{t\to 0}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|} $ not to be $ 0 \cdot $

Comment: My $g$ is continuous. Moreover, by choosing $h$ to be a smooth bump function instead of a triangle, you can even make $g$ infinitely differentiable.

Comment: I see. In deed your $ g $ is continuous and its integral converges. Nice counterexample. Thank you for making things look pretty clear to me. I've noticed now the detail that I had missed up to then.